# Optimizing thread calls in Java

Tags: java, java-threads

TokenGenerator.main() (called at the bottom) is used to generate 10 character alphanumeric tokens and write them to a text file. I want to try to produce as many of these as possible.

I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this:

```
package Random;

public class TokenStarter implements Runnable {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Thread(new TokenStarter()).start();
    new Thread(new TokenStarter()).start();
    new Thread(new TokenStarter()).start();
    new Thread(new TokenStarter()).start();
    new Thread(new TokenStarter()).start();
    new Thread(new TokenStarter()).start();
    new Thread(new TokenStarter()).start();
    new Thread(new TokenStarter()).start();
    new Thread(new TokenStarter()).start();
    new Thread(new TokenStarter()).start();
    new Thread(new TokenStarter()).start();
    new Thread(new TokenStarter()).start();

}

    @Override
    public void run() {
        TokenGenerator.main(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all: If you need to add Lorem ipsum so your question is even postable you should definitely rethink if this is a good question.
Second: Have you heard of loops? Third: What is this code supposed to even do?

Comment: What is that supposed to do?

Comment: @GhostCat without trying to take this too far into meta-territory I think there is a border where it goes from being welcoming and helpful over to trying to salvage anything usable from something unusable in an attempt to not be unwelcoming.

Comment: @AlexRitchie **DO NOT** [insult other users](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50253248/3), this is a violation of Stack Overflow's [Be Nice](/help/be-nice) policy.

Comment: If your aim is to write a stream of tokens to a single output file, then threading will only help if the process of token generation is very expensive.  Otherwise, writing to the file will be a single-threaded bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop and an `ExecutorService`.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    executor.execute(new TokenStarter());
}
```

That should recreate your code, but is not optimal. You probably want to limit the amount of threads that run concurrently:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(desiredParallelism);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes: learn about *loops*, and more importantly, don't use raw threads, and especially so many of them.

Instead, create a **single** executor service instance (backed by well known and **meaningful** number of threads) and push tasks into that service.

Anything else is like "year 2000 style". Hard to control, hard to test, hard to maintain, ...

And finally: learn that just "adding many threads" isn't an answer, but rather a problem in disguise. When performance (throughput, latency, ...) really matters to you then you will have to carefully measure what is really going on, and then focus on optiziming the **true** bottle necks.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use a `for-loop` and `Executors` which is better to control and create Thread pool :

```
ExecutorService exe = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    exe.submit(new TokenStarter());
}
exe.shutdown();
exe.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS); // if need to wait
```

Comment: [`ExecutorService.submit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)) does only handle `Callables`. Since op passed his class to a new Thread it propably implements the `Runnable` interface and you should have used `exe.execute(new TokenStarter())` in your example. Otherwise it's the perfect example.

Comment: @L.Spillner maybe there is [ExecutorService.submit(Runnable)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-) ;)

Comment: ops, my bad didn't saw it. Recalled a colleague who told me to use execute for `Runnable`s and submit for `Callable`s.